# How to write .htaccess file for AJAX page

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, .htaccess

I am working on a website which i am going to develop as a CMS. So i am writing .htaccess file. page link and url working fine, but when i performing ajax request then i am getting 404 error for the url. I am placing my .htaccess file code and the ajax request which i am calling.

**.htaccess file**

```
RewriteRule ^single _single_Page.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^single/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ _single_Page.php?subid=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^findcontents/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ _findContentTitle.php?data=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**AJAX request using JQuery**

```
$('.search').keyup(function(e){
    var data=$(this).val();
    data="data="+data;
    $.ajax({
        url:'/findcontents',
        type:'POST',
        data:data,
        success:function(result){
            if(result==""){
                $('.result p').html("No result found.<br>Please make correct search.");
            }else{
                $('.result p').html(result);
            }
            $('.result').css('visibility','visible');
        },
        error:function(error){console.log(error);}
    });

});
```

Please friends tell me where i am wrong, as i need to fix it out as soon as possible.

Thanks....

Comment: What is actual URL called from your ajax script and to what it should be re-written?

Comment: what ever written in above ajax calling i am using the same. but the problem is solved by the below answer. Now each and everything working till now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's more related to apache than ajax. Anyway - your RewriteRule is `^findcontents/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$` and you post to the url `'/findcontents'`. Did you try to post to `'/findcontents/asdf'` ?
Another option is to add `^findcontents$` to your rules.

If none of these works for you please provide some more information from the server's log.

Comment: Thanks Dekel, Your first option '/findcontents/asdf' working. but what about if i want to perform ajax request by post method only as given in the above question.

Comment: Check the rest of my reply... you should add ^findcontents$ to your rules.

When you post to /findcontents that string doesn't match ^findcontents/SOMETEXT$ (like your current rule).